# How can I plot these two variables below?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(data=daily_kpi2)+
  x="total_distance", y="total_steps"
```

Here is the error message

> Error: unexpected ',' in: "ggplot(data=daily_kpi2)+
> x="total_distance","
>
> Error in fetch(key) :    lazy-load database
> '/home/rstudio-user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/ggplot2/help/ggplot2.rdb'
> is corrupt

Comment: Try ggplot(data=daily_kpi2)+ aes(x="total_distance", y="total_steps")

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but can you tell me why? Does it have to do with where independent and dependent variables are plotted?

Comment: The aes() can be inside or outside the ggplot(), but is necessary for th ggplot syntax, here some reference: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/